# Building on Centos, Zlib.h error while installing PerlIO::gzip

Tags: linux, centos, gzip, zlib, perl-module

I'm using Centos6, trying to install PerlIO::gzip
error that I get is

> ```
> gzip.xs:16:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
> #include <zlib.h>
> ^~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [gzip.o] Error 1
> ```

how can I deal with this

I have tried many solutions from web but none of them worked. some of them are as below:

**yum install libpng libpng-devel**

```
Package 2:libpng-1.2.49-2.el6_7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 2:libpng-devel-1.2.49-2.el6_7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

**sudo yum install libpng-devel gd-devel zlib-devel perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker**

```
Package 2:libpng-devel-1.2.49-2.el6_7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gd-devel-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.55-144.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

**sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"**

```
Package flex-2.5.35-9.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.4.7-18.el6_9.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-51.el6.centos.noarch already installed and latest version
Package rpm-build-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.81-23.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package patch-2.6-8.el6_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gettext-0.17-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package bison-2.4.1-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-18.el6_9.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package patchutils-0.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package byacc-1.9.20070509-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package indent-2.2.10-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package systemtap-2.9-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package diffstat-1.51-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package elfutils-0.164-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package cvs-1.11.23-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package rcs-5.7-37.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package subversion-1.6.11-15.el6_7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-18.el6_9.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:doxygen-1.6.1-6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package git-1.7.1-9.el6_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ctags-5.8-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package cscope-15.6-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package swig-1.3.40-6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Warning: Group development does not have any packages.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Just got that problem on Ubuntu, solution was to install `zlib1g-dev`.

`cpan install PerlIO::gzip` worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

I did this on my Fedora and that did the trick:

```
sudo dnf install zlib-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `yum install perl-Compress-Zlib`.

Comment: This module is also present. **Package perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-144.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version**

Answer (score 0):

I even tried installing it manually but could not succeed.
Please find the details below

**[root@localhost PerlIO-gzip-0.20]# perl Makefile.PL**

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PerlIO::gzip
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

**[root@localhost PerlIO-gzip-0.20]# make**

```
cp gzip.pm blib/lib/PerlIO/gzip.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for gzip ()
chmod 644 "gzip.bs"
"/home/Ranjan/Softwares/Perl-5.26.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- gzip.bs blib/arch/auto/PerlIO/gzip/gzip.bs 644
"/home/Ranjan/Softwares/Perl-5.26.1/bin/perl" "/home/Ranjan/Softwares/Perl-5.26.1/lib/perl5/5.26.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/home/Ranjan/Softwares/Perl-5.26.1/lib/perl5/5.26.1/ExtUtils/typemap'  gzip.xs > gzip.xsc
mv gzip.xsc gzip.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.20\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.20\" -fPIC "-I/home/Ranjan/Softwares/Perl-5.26.1/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   gzip.c
gzip.xs:16:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zlib.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [gzip.o] Error 1
```